# Delphi MSBuild Build Android From Command Line that selects App Store or Development platform configuration

Tags: delphi

What I want to parametertise is the platform configuration, so that I can specifically build an APK for the AppStore.

```
msbuild MyProject.dproj /p:Config=Release /t:Build;Deploy /p:Platform=Android
```

Currently whatever is actually selected/saved to Project File, the msbuild always builds the development platform configuration for release.

[Platform Configuration Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZE04.jpg)

I've tried a few possible /p parameters (such as buildtype etc) but none of them seem to work.

How to do this?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659848/how-to-build-android-apk-from-command-line

Comment: Thanx, but it doesn't go into the Release configuration (at the platform level) choices around App Store or Development.

Comment: No. That's why I said "related". I just wanted to link the two questions, so that there is useful metadata

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this command-line (broken across 2 lines to avoid scrollers) and it produced the output expected for an App-Store build:

```
msbuild project_name.dproj /p:Config=Debug /t:Build;Deploy
    /p:Platform=Android /p:BT_BuildType=AppStore
```

This gave:

> ....blah blah...
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets :
>   warning :
>   Missing provisioning information for the "Application Store" platform configuration,
>   the file '.\Android\Debug\project_name\bin\project_name.apk' has been sucessfully
>   generated but it has not been signed and it is a non-instalable package.

This is not normally output on my build, and I hadn't set up suitable app-store provisioning, so it suggests we are getting the desired results.

It seems that for Android the `BT_BuildType` property can either be `Debug` or `AppStore`. For iOS it can also be `AdHoc`.